# Можно ли использовать OpenSSL для шифрования GET-параметра?

Tags: php, get, шифрование, openssl, urlencode

Передаю данные GET-запросом, данные **конфиденциальные**, шифрую их с помощью `OpenSSL`:

```
$method = "AES-128-CBC";
$result = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, 0, $iv);
header('Location: http://site.com/?hash=' . $result);
```

Всё работает нормально до тех пор, пока в строке `$result`, передаваемой в качестве значения GET-запроса, не оказываются определенные символы. Например, значение `hash` из адреса `http://site.com/?hash=JHFfB+ET1k=` (содержит символ `+`), будет прочитано как `JHFfB ET1k=` (пробел вместо символа `+`), т.е. расшифровать это уже нельзя.

Прошу совета у тех кто разбирается, существуют ли способы исключить определенные символы из результата шифрования, например, использованием того или иного метода или алгоритма шифрования? Или OpenSSL не подходит для работы с данными для GET-запроса?

Можно ли надежно шифровать передаваемые данные?

Comment: В base64 кодируйте после шифрования.

Comment: протупил... Спасибо большое! Напишите в виде ответа.

Comment: @Visman а поможет? Base64 имеет в алфавите тот же самый плюс. Да и "JHFfB+ET1k=" уже похоже не base64...

Comment: Base64 -- это не шифрование, можно легко получить данные обратно. Также, давайте определимся, откуда и куда вы передаёте данные? Если из браузера пользователя какую-то ссылку передаёте или в браузер пользователя -- то всегда можно увидеть/остановить редирект, посмотреть передаваемые данные. Вам нужно прямо именно зашифровать так, чтобы было нельзя расшифровать? Возможно, вам нужно всего лишь [url encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) / url decode?

Comment: Внёс уточнение в вопрос, речь идет именно о шифровании данных, которые нужно передать get-запросом. Предложенный @Visman способ проверил, точно работает. Сейчас проверю способ @A K.

Comment: Зачем передавать конфиденциальные данные в адресе?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, что-то я глупость сморозил :) Попутал со своим методом вставки шифрованной строки в скрытое поле формы отправляемой методом post.

Comment: @Visman, оборачивание результата шифрования в base64 решило мои проблемы с передачей результата шифрования. К слову, обертка в виде urlencode - не решила (если честно, я так и не разобрался, почему), хотя и принял ответ, поскольку на _прямой вопрос_ о корректной обработке символа "плюс" он верен. Прошу прощения, если и мой первоначальный вопрос, и поздние комментарии покажутся скомканными. В любом случае, ответ ищущим информацию на тему передачи произвольных символов в адресной строке так или иначе дан.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если проблема только в том, что передаются знаки типа " " (пробел), "+" и другие -- то стандартно применяют функцию [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php), а не шифрование.

```
echo 'http://site/?hash=' . urlencode('JHFfB+ET');
// http://site/?hash=JHFfB%2BET
```

Поэтому после того, как данные зашифруете -- оберните в urlencode.